# Transforming a Mobile Coordinate System to a Stationary Coordinate System

Tags: matrices, coordinate-systems, rotations

[image]

The above image describes the problem I am facing with the 'prime' system being the mobile one. I am only working in a 2D coordinate system and I am looking to get the angle between the x-axes of each coordinate system. The point is stationary at $(1,0)$ in the stationary coordinate frame, which gives the vector $r$, and the vectors $r'$ and $r_0$ are also known.

I have currently been using a rotation matrix in the form of $v' = Rv + t$ where $v'$ is the $r$ vector, $v$ is the $r'$ vector, and $t$ is the $r_0$ vector in the image. For the following equations, I am usually an $s$ subscript for the stationary system and an $m$ subscript for the mobile one.

$\left\lgroup\matrix{1 \cr 0}\right\rgroup = \left\lgroup\matrix{\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta)\cr \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)}\right\rgroup \left\lgroup\matrix{x_m \cr y_m}\right\rgroup + \left\lgroup\matrix{x_s \cr y_s}\right\rgroup$

In testing, this has seemed to be an issue when the mobile coordinate system is close (within 2-5 meters) to the origin of the stationary coordinate system. I am calculating the angle from

$\theta = \cos^{-1}(\frac{x_m - y_s*y_m - x_s*x_m}{x_m^2 + y_m^2})$.

This seems to be accurate for the angle magnitude, but in some cases ends up off from the correct angle but with some increment of 90 degrees. I am not certain that this is the correct angle calculation and I would encourage feedback on if this is the best way to approach getting the rotation angle between two coordinate systems.

Comment: Please use MathJax to display formulas and embed the image directly into your question so that one can read it easily

Comment: I am unable to directly embed the image due to being a new user. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: It's hard to say how to fix your method when we don't know what it is or have any specific example of how it goes wrong.

Comment: What is the problem exactly ?  What are you looking to find out ?

Comment: I have updated the end of my posting to hopefully make it clear that I am not certain about my solution as there are still issues in some test cases and whether this is the best method for this issue.

Comment: The image shows three dimensional frames.  But in the text of the problem you seem to be referring to two-dimensional frames.  Why is that ?

Comment: It was an image that helped me visualize the problem, despite being only in a two-dimensional frame. Apologies for the confusion and for not creating my own image to accurately portray my specific problem.